# How to generate error message in EF Core OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to generate desired error message if `Email` or `UserName` are not unique. Using Swagger API, at the moment I just get really big response saying I cant insert duplicate value into a table. I want to replace it with error message like "Username already exists".

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserEntityConfiguration());

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
           .HasIndex(u => new { u.Email, u.UserName})
           .IsUnique();
}
```

Comment: In `OnModelCreating` you can specify only Unique Keys. Validation should be done in controller.

Comment: You should enforce some separation on concern as `OnModelCreating` job should only be mapping your data structure to your business model. Your use-case is exactly what the `[Remote]` attribute is for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#remote-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to change the error message in `OnModelCreating`. If you accept, you can do the validation in the controller and customize the error message.

You can refer to the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(UserTest userTest)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         try
         {
              _context.UserTest.Add(userTest);
              _context.SaveChanges();
              return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
              var sqlException = GetInnerException<SqlException>(ex);

              if (sqlException != null
                        && (sqlException.Number == 2627 || sqlException.Number == 2601))
              {
                   ViewData["Message"] = "Username already exists";
                   return View();
              }
         }
    }
    return View();
}

public TException GetInnerException<TException>(Exception exception)
where TException : Exception
{
     Exception innerException = exception;
     while (innerException != null)
     {
         if (innerException is TException result)
         {
             return result;
         }
         innerException = innerException.InnerException;
     }
     return null;
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: It's much easier to use the https://github.com/Giorgi/EntityFramework.Exceptions library. That way you don't need to hardcode error numbers in your code and you can simply catch UniqueConstraintException